# bundle exec rake test does nothing

Tags: ruby, tdd, bundler, rake-task

I am trying to get my heads "dirty" with TDD and for some reason when I run `bundle exec rake test` on the command line, nothing happens.

Here is my `RakeFile`:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |test|
  test.libs << 'test'
end

desc "Run Tests"
task :default => :test
```

Here is my test file:

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestMygem < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_silly_example
    assert_equal 2+2, 5
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you migrated the db? rake `db:migrate` ?

Comment: There is nothing to migrate... this is a simple RubyGem I am working on

Comment: Found it! I forgot to add `test.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']` to my RakeFile

Comment: It's best to add an answer with that if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 9):

I forgot to add this line to my `RakeFile`

```
test.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']
```

So, all in all, here is my final `RakeFile`

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |test|
  test.libs << 'test'
  test.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']
end

desc "Run Tests"
task :default => :test
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Rails 3.2.20, the following is acceptable

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = 'test/_test*.rb'
  t.verbose = false # or true
end

desc "Run Tests"
task :default => :test
```